# How can I make an external C++ static library and use it in my main C project with cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, static

I've been trying to create an external C++ static library to be used in my main project in C with cmake but didn't manage to have it working.
The library will contain several algorithms in a hidden layer and an interface layer to be able to feed the algos and get the output out of it.

**Here are the main project and the library directories structure:**

- MyMainProject

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - Inc

    - someOtherFiles.h
  - Src

    - main.c
    - someOtherFiles.c
  - MyLibraryOutputs

    - interface.h
    - libMyLibrary.a
- MyLibrary

  - CmakeLists.txt
  - cmake-build-debug

    - libMyLibrary.a
  - Inc

    - interface.h
  - Src

    - Headers

      - algorithm.h
    - interface.cpp
    - algorithm.cpp

**MyMainProject/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(MyMainProject C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Os -g3 -std=gnu11 -std=c11 -lm -lc -mcpu=cortex-m4-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -fstack-usage")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Os -g3 -lm -lc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -fstack-usage")
set(C_FLAGS "${C_FLAGS} --std=gnu99")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Src/main.c Src/someOtherFiles.c)
include_directories(Inc)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MyLibraryOutputs/libMyLibrary.a)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MyLibraryOutputs)
```

**MyMainProject/Src/main.c**

```
#include "interface.h"

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;

    sum = sumFromMyLibrary(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

**MyMainProject/MyLibraryOutputs/interface.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int sumFromMyLibrary(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**MyLibrary/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(MyLibrary
        VERSION 1.0.0
        DESCRIPTION "algorithms library"
        LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -O0 -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Src/interface.cpp Src/algorithm.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        Src
        Src/Headers
        PUBLIC
        Inc)
```

**MyLibrary/Inc/interface.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int sumFromMyLibrary(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**MyLibrary/Src/interface.cpp**

```
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "interface.h" // Edit

int sumFromMyLibrary(int x, int y) {
    return sumAlgorithm(x, y);
}
```

**MyLibrary/Src/Headers/algorithm.h**

```
int sumAlgorithm(int m, int n);
```

**MyLibrary/Src/algorithm.cpp**

```
#include "algorithms.h"

int sumAlgorithm(int m, int n) {
    return m + n;
}
```

With those files, when I build the MyLibrary target, I get a libMyLibrary.a archive that I copy and paste to the MyMainProject/MyLibraryOutputs along with the interface.h file.

However, when I try to build my main.c, i get the following error:

````
```
... undefined reference to `sumFromMyLibrary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [MyMainProject] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyMainProject.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyMainProject.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [MyMainProject] Error 2
```
````

What am I doing wrong ?
I know that the issue is in the CMakeLists.txt of either MyLibrary or MyMainProject but I can't say where.

Comment: if you did not install `MyLibrary`, the you can just use `add_subdirectory(path/to/MyLibrary)` which will make the library named `libMyLibrary.a` known to cmake. then you can do `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} MyLibrary)` to link the libraries. Note that with this approach, building your main project will also build your library

Comment: In the `MyLibrary/Src/interface.cpp` you **define** the function `sumFromMyLibrary` but forgot to include the header file `interface.h` which **declares** it. Because of that C++ compiler is not aware that you want to define a function in C style (as `extern "C"`) and instead defines the function in C++ style. That is why you got error ``... undefined reference to `sumFromMyLibrary'`` - there is no definition of function `sumFromMyLibrary` in C style.

Comment: In `MyMainProject/CMakeLists.txt`, did you forget to add `MyLibraryOutputs` to the `include_directories()` list?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I wasn't using the same compiler for the library and the main project.

If encountering this issue, make sure the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER are set to the same compiler in the CMakeLists.txt.